# Infinite Sum with Geometric and Combinatorial terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I was working on a probability question which at one point brought me to the sum:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \Big{(}\frac{4}{6}\Big{)}^k  {4+k \choose k}$$

I put it in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A%28%284%2F6%29%5En%29+%28%284%2Bn%29choose%28n%29%29%2F%2F%5D+from+%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A0%2F%2F%5D+to+%5B%2F%2Fmath%3AInfinity%2F%2F%5D) and obtained the answer $243$. That answer also gives me the correct answer to my original probability problem.

I have tried re expressing the combinatorial term as factorials, but cannot seem to simplify it any further. I could have sworn this type of sum was covered in my undergraduate studies...but cannot find any references.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $\binom{4+k}{k}=(k+4)(k+3)(k+2)(k+1)/24$.  Expand this polynomial.  It's not hard to find $\sum a^k k^n$ for fixed $n$.

Answer (score 2):

In general you have for $|x|<1$
$$\frac 1{(1-x)^{n+1}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{n+k}k x^k$$

In your case you get as sum $3^5 = 243$.

Comment: any particular name of this series, So that I can find and study more about it?

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi: Check for *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series#Special_cases)*

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi
It's a nice exercise to derive the above formula from the geometric series $\frac 1{1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$. A possible way is by differentiating.